# Jump agent (no resources) from objects

Tags: anylogic

How can i move agent for example from Delay to Another Delay without connect them with a path.

The reason is that I want to design process to show it better.

I want to show main business process , and sub process , so agent will can move to sub process.

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use enter and exit blocks...

after your first delay, add an exit block called exit, and before the second delay add an enter block called enter.

Then on the exit block action code, write down the following

```
enter.take(agent);
```

This will teleport your agent from the exit to the enter block
These blocks are present in the Process Modeling Library